# decoding json data into a list to display in a listView

Tags: json, flutter

I have a simple Json file (list of names) and I need to display the data from it in a ListView widget:

```
{
  "peoplesnames": [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3",
    "name4",
    "name5",
    "name6",
    "name7",
    "name8"
  ]
}
```

I've created the getter in a stateful widget as seen below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class test extends StatefulWidget {
  const test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<test> createState() => _testState();
}

class _testState extends State<test> {
  
  void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('www.genericwebsite.com'),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      var names = jsonDecode(data)['names'];
      print(names);
      return names;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(children: [
        
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run this code it works! I can see the names printed in the console.

what I now need help with please, is turning that data into a list and then getting it to display in the listView widget.
I was informed in a previous post to use
List names = await getData;
but no matter where I put this in my code, it was throwing back errors.

thanks so much for your time and patience.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can do following thing

```
class _testState extends State<test> {
 //Creating List Variable with empty list
 List<String> peopleNames = [];
  
  void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('www.genericwebsite.com'),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      final names = jsonDecode(data);
      print(names); //
      peopleNames.addAll((List<String>.from(names['peoplesnames']));//If and only if this is list
      setState(() {});
      return names;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
         shrinkWrap: true,
         itemCount: peopleNames.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return Text(peopleNames[index].toString());
         }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, thanks so much for the reply. i'm getting the error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<String>'. when as list is at the end of:  peopleNames.addAll((names['peoplenames'] as List)); and if i remove as list, and then run it, i get the same error. is it something wrong with the json file that is stopping it from saving as a list? cheers

Comment: Can you print this names['peoplenames'] and add in next comment

Comment: Hi, If I comment out the list builder and also peopleNames.addAll((names['peoplenames'] as List)); when I print names['peoplenames'] it displays the names from the json in the console but weirdly it does it continuously like on a loop

Comment: here is the error im getting in the console when I remove as List. (Ican't run it with as List)[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<String>'

Comment: Can you try to do  `peopleNames.addAll(jsonDecode(names['peoplenames'])];`

Comment: hi i found a fix in another post. peopleNames.addAll((List<String>.from(names['peoplesnames'])); to replace peopleNames.addAll((names['peoplenames'] as List));